# Macro processor tries too hard without curly braces

Tags: discussion, macro, prosessing

Given this MWE;

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\def\ee{\=e\=e}

\begin{document}
    sh\ee{n}g ur k\=asn
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to eliminate the curly braces that prevent the macro processor from becoming confused and looking for another macro name? Similar to the way that `\=a` does not consume the following s. I have just now noticed that the `\ee` will consume the following space for reasons I do not have sufficient LaTeX-Fu to correct other than with a pair of closed braces `{}.`

Comment: Will someone with the power move this to regular TeX?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be asked on the main site.

Comment: @CarLaTex Am I correct in thinking that there is no ability to move questions to the correct place?

Comment: I'll ask admins to do it.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Thanks!